Drush 10.6 taking forever to run command "drush cr"
I am trying to upgrade drupal 9.5 to drupal 10. For that, i have upgraded php version to 8.1.6 from 7.4 as drupal suggest. I have fixed some packages and composer install working fine. But now i am stuck with drush command.
drush cr

Above command is running for hours but not finished. Is there some kind of issue in drush 10.6 when php upgraded to 8.1.6. When i checked drush status , everything seems good. Please help me guys.

try to clear cache from the admin section.

sometimes things get stuck in opcache and a webserver restart might help

Also maybe adding -vvv gives you more information where it is stuck

try clearing cache one by one by using drush cc and see which point you are getting struck.
